# How to retrive facebook users access token using graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using graph api and i am login through facebook in my app
My login link is as

```
var authorize_url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?";
    authorize_url += "client_id=" + client_id;
    authorize_url += "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri;
    authorize_url += "&display="+ ( display ? display : "touch" );
    authorize_url += "&scope=user_about_me,publish_stream,manage_pages,user_interests,friends_interests,user_birthday,friends_birthday,user_education_history,friends_education_history";
    authorize_url += "&type=user_agent";
```

there is no problem here,all works well.

But problem is,it returns me **"APP ACCESS TOKEN"** not "**USER ACCESS TOKEN**". all i need is user access token to fetch mutual friends list b/w two users.
i surf a lot and tried all stuff but no luck yet.
can any one help me out ?

Comment: why did you repeat your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14936018/1405120

Comment: and what platform are you using?

Comment: @ThePCWizard : i just ask question in diffrent way,because i am not getting solution. i am using phonegap and using javascript api for login with facebook. but instead of user access token i always get app access token. and all stuff i tried but still i always get app accesstoken

Comment: ok, have you added the Javascript SDK into your website??

Comment: @ThePCWizard : i am using phonegap and creating native app for IOS so there is no website.and other thing is that all is working fine like i am fetching interestlist,friends list, etc. ther was no issue yet.but now i want to fetch mutual friend b/w two users which need access token of loged-in user.thats the main problem. till now i was just using token of app there was no issue in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get access token in javascript sdk.

```
       function login() {
            FB.login(function (response) {                    
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // connected
                    var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    console.log("Token: " + token);                        
                } else {
                    // cancelled
                } 
            }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
        }
```

Comment: its also giving me access token of app not user

Comment: are you sure? have you debugged it here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/